# Is there a special way to send data via arduino through BLE

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently trying to send data (text mainly) from my Arduino card + Seeed BLE Shield HM-11, but I am having. I can send text from my android Bluetooth Terminal without troubles but when it comes to receiving data on my phone from the shield, it doesn't work and does not raise any exception.

Note that the led only served to verify the phone and the shield were connected.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>   //Software Serial Port

#define RxD         3
#define TxD         4

#define PINLED      7

#define LEDON()     digitalWrite(PINLED, HIGH)
#define LEDOFF()    digitalWrite(PINLED, LOW)

#define DEBUG_ENABLED  1

SoftwareSerial Bluetooth(RxD, TxD);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(RxD, INPUT);
  pinMode(TxD, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PINLED, OUTPUT);
  LEDOFF();

  setupBlueToothConnection();
}

void loop()
{
  char recvChar;

  while(true)
  {
    if (Bluetooth.available())
    { //check if there's any data sent from the remote bluetooth shield
      recvChar = Bluetooth.read();

      Serial.print(recvChar);
      if (recvChar == '1')
      {
        LEDON();
        Bluetooth.write("Led ON");
      }
      else if (recvChar == '0')
      {
        LEDOFF();
      }
    }
  }
}




/***************************************************************************
   Function Name: setupBlueToothConnection
   Description:  initilizing bluetooth connction
   Parameters:
   Return:
***************************************************************************/
void setupBlueToothConnection()
{



  Bluetooth.begin(9600);

  Bluetooth.print("AT");
  delay(400);

  Bluetooth.print("AT+DEFAULT");             // Restore all setup value to factory setup
  delay(2000);

  Bluetooth.print("AT+NAMESeeedBTSlave");    // set the bluetooth name as "SeeedBTSlave" ,the length of bluetooth name must less than 12 characters.
  delay(400);

  Bluetooth.print("AT+PIN0000");             // set the pair code to connect
  delay(400);

  Bluetooth.print("AT+AUTH1");             //
  delay(400);

  Bluetooth.print("AT+NOTI1");             //
  delay(400);


  Bluetooth.flush();

}
```

I wanted that code to answer "LED ON" when it receives '1' but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the while (true) {} wrapper from around your loop() code. Because Arduino calls loop() over and over, the loop() function acts as a while (true) loop.

Having your loop() function never return - as your code currently does - prevents the processor from doing other things, such as running the Bluetooth stack. I haven't written Arduino Bluetooth code, but I've seen a similar problem when using Wifi: if the loop() takes too long, the background functions can fail.

Your corrected loop() function should look like this:

```
void loop()
{
  char recvChar;

  if (Bluetooth.available())
  { //check if there's any data sent from the remote bluetooth shield
    recvChar = Bluetooth.read();

    Serial.print(recvChar);
    if (recvChar == '1')
    {
      LEDON();
      Bluetooth.write("Led ON");
    }
    else if (recvChar == '0')
    {
      LEDOFF();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this as soon as possible